# RStudio ioslides, mathjax, what the heck?

Tags: latex, shiny, rstudio, mathjax

So typically I use beamer for presentations, but I thought what the heck just for fun I would do a ioslides presentation so I could embed a shiny app into the presentation. For the most part making the slides has been pretty smooth, but I cannot seem to get any of the math latex setting to work. Here is a toy example where I simply want the KM estimator to display

````
    ---
title: "test"
author: "tes"
date: "1/1/16"
output: 
        ioslides_presentation:
        widescreen: true
        mathjax: "http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"
        runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Test

$$
\hat{S}(t)=\prod_{y_{(i)}\leq t}\hat{p}_{t}=\prod_{y_{(i)}\leq t}\dfrac{n_{i}-d_{i}}{n_{i}}=\prod_{i=1}^{k}\dfrac{n_{i}-d_{i}}{n_{i}} & \quad\textrm{where }y_{k}\leq t<y_{k+1} 
$$
````

All I get is a slide with a simple wireframe box around the latex call (e.g the \hat{S}(t)=\prod_{y_{(I)}...  I should note that I have also tried just simply wrapping with single $ to no avail.

What am I missing? - I looked all over the R markdown documentation but I cannot see to figure it out.

Simple latex calls work jut fine, for example

```
$x^{2}$
```

renders exactly as I would expect.

I assume this is something silly, but it is besting me.

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used these things in a while but I think your indentation on the "ioslides_presentation:" line shouldn't be indented quite that far.  Not sure if it matters but it does look off to me.

Comment: Does using `\[` and `\]` to start and end the blocks work?

Comment: Nope to both - I messed with adjusting the indentation - no change, and I tried using the `\[` and the `\]` already to no avail. My apologies for leaving that out of the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation is actually not valid.  It contains an ampersand (`&`) that is not within an alignment, so MathJax rejects it.  If you remove the ampersand, I suspect it will work for you.

If there is a way to configure MathJax from within your slides, you could disabled the noErrors extension so that the actual error messages will be displayed rather than the boxed source.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. I ended up abandoning the ioslides due to time constraints, but this will definitely be of use in the future.